# When a notification's clicked, open an activity

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

My code:

```
public class OnAlarmReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
      {
          CharSequence title = "Hello";
          CharSequence message = "la!";
          NotificationManager notificationManager;
          notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService("notification");
          Notification notification;
          notification = new Notification(com.example.pack.R.drawable.ic_launcher, "test", System.currentTimeMillis());

          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);

          notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pendingIntent);
          notificationManager.notify(1010, notification);

      }
}
```

I use alarmmanager for receive, how can I open an activity when user clicks on notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your declaration of the PendingIntent:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);
```

With something like this that would describe the intent to start the activity you want to launch (change the 3rd argument accordingly)

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), new Intent(this, YourAppClass.class), 0);
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much @Matthieu. Just maybe you could explain the answer a little bit if you have some time? Thanks.

Comment: The best is probably to look at the documentation from Google... you should check this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateANotification

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my application for when my app receives a wake up call from alarmmanager

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName(); 


@Override   
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Received wake up from alarm manager.");

    long rowid = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

    WakeReminderIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class); 
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowid);  
    context.startService(i);
```

Strings.xml

```
 <!-- Notification Bar -->
<string name="notify_new_task_message">Wake up!</string>
<string name="notify_new_task_title">Wake up! reminder</string>
```

Wakereminderintentservice is another java file i have to wake the phone up.

ReminderService.java

```
 public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {

   public ReminderService() {
    super("ReminderService");
        }

@Override
void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("ReminderService", "Doing work.");
    Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

    NotificationManager mgr =  (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class); 
    notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

    Notification note=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_title), getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), pi);
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 

    // An issue could occur if user ever enters over 2,147,483,647 tasks. (Max int value). 
    // I highly doubt this will ever happen. But is good to note. 
    int id = (int)((long)rowId);
    mgr.notify(id, note); 


    }
}
```

Hope any of this code helps you.